# Rendering Special Characters in PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf

We are trying to generate a PDF file from a HTML template which has non-english characters.

We are using `body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }` as the **css** for the body.

The issue is with the below tag. If we use `escape="true"`, the special characters are rendered but along with them, the html tags are also rendered in the PDF. If we set `escape="false"`, the html tags along with the special characters disappear.
Is there a way to make the special characters render but not the html tags?

```
apex:outputText value="xyz" escape="false" style="align:left"
```